# How to get the total number of minutes from a date string?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, hour, minute

From the back-end, I am retrieving this string as a date: `"2017-08-16T18:35:41.611Z2017-08-16T13:35:41.611"`

How can I extract the total number of minutes from this string? I tried the following:

```
let date = new Date("2017-08-16T18:35:41.611Z2017-08-16T13:35:41.611");
let minutes = date.getMinutes();
console.log(minutes);
```

But `date` logs as `Invalid Date` and `minutes` logs as `NaN`. Any ideas?

Comment: That's 2 DateTime's inside 1 string. Parsing will fail. Is it supposed to be 2 dates?

Comment: what do you mean by total number of minutes?

Comment: @samnupel For example, if the backend gives 18 hours and 5 minutes, the total number of minutes would be (18*60 + 5). Also, I will accept Frankusky's answer once I'm allowed to. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be two dates, one ""2017-08-16T18:35:41.611Z" and the other "2017-08-16T13:35:41.611", which infers that the second with timezone offset should be "2017-08-16T13:35:41.611-0500".

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backend is sending you twice the date
**2017-08-16T18:35:41.611Z**2017-08-16T13:35:41.611

If you can't modify the backend service, you could split them by the Z and then do the function you said:

```
let date = new Date("2017-08-16T18:35:41.611Z2017-08-16T13:35:41.611".split("Z")[0]);
let minutes = date.getMinutes();
console.log(minutes);
```

Comment: This will change the timezone used for parsing from Z to local, and the required result would be `date.getHours()*60 + date.getMinutes()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your date string I see two dates.

```
dateString = "2017-08-16T18:35:41.611Z2017-08-16T13:35:41.611"

dates  = x.split('Z')

console.log("date1 :", new Date(dates[0])
console.log("date1 :", new Date(dates[1])
```

hope that helps

Comment: Unless the host system is set to UTC+0000, this changes the timezone of the first date.